# Добавления свойств в класс

Tags: ооп, javascript

Помогите разобратся с шаблоном И практике его применения

```
 <script>
    var Class = function() { 
      var klass = function() {
        this.init.apply(this, arguments); //объясните пожалуйста здесь,что это такое
      };

      klass.prototype.init = function() { };

      klass.fn = klass.prototype;

      klass.fn.parent = klass;//прокоментируйте пожалуйста зачем такое делать
      // Adding class properties 
      klass.extend = function(obj) {
        var extended = obj.extended; 
        for(var i in obj) {
          klass[i] = obj[i]; 
        }

        if (extended) extended(klass) 
      };

      klass.include = function(obj) {
        var included = obj.included; 
        for(var i in obj) {
          klass.fn[i] = obj[i]; 
        }

        if (included) included(klass) 
      };

      return klass; 
    };

    var Person = new Class;

    //Using extend
    Person.extend({
      find: function(id) {  }, 
      exists: function(id) {  },
      // using the extended hook
      extended: function(klass) {
        alert(klass, " was extended!"); 
      }
    });

    Person.find(1);

    //Using include
    Person.include({
      save: function(id) {  },
      destroy: function(id) {  } 
    });

    var person = new Person; 
    person.save();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

узнаю примеры из книги `Javascript Web Applications`

```
this.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

это означает, что функция `init`, которую вы переопределите в своём классе, допустим `Person` будет выступать в роли конструктора

пример:

```
Person.include({
  init: function(){
      console.log('Person instance initiated');
  }
});

var person = new Person(); // log: Person instance initiated
```

---

```
klass.fn.parent = klass;
```

а это означает, что в все объекты созданные с помощью вашего класса `Person` всегда будут иметь ссылку на родителя, такой аналог `super`, по-моему его применение описывается в следующем примере из этой книги в разделе `Adding Inheritance to Our Class Library`

Comment: Спасибо Spectre.Очень часто выручаешь.Да ,это именно та книга которую ты советовал по изучению MVC.Очень сложная книга для меня.Стефанов отдыхает... Буду дальше учить книгу.Подобных вещей нету в других...Ссылку на родителя посмотрю дальше

Answer (score 0):

http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/